# How to use mysqli_fetch_assoc in custom php function?

Tags: php, mysql, function

I'm new in php function is it possible to use mysqli_fetch_assoc in php function?

here's what I'm doing.

function.php

```
<?php
        function getinfoid($conn,$idapplicant){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM applicants WHERE id_mis = '".$idapplicant."' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $prefix=$row['prefix'];
        $fname1=$row['fname'];
        $mname1=$row['mname'];
        $lname1=$row['lname'];
        $gender=$row['gender'];
        $addr=$row['addr'];
        }
    }
?>
```

view.php

```
    <?php 
    require('connection.php'); 
    include ('function.php');
    getinfoid($conn,'2');
    ?>
I'm <?php echo $fname1 ?>
```

how is it possible to echo $fname1 ?

Comment: Return a value from the function

Comment: You can build an array and return the array from which you can fetch the corresponding value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need to print only `$fname1`, following is my proposed solution:

You need to return `$fname1` from your function.

```
<?php
function getinfoid($conn,$idapplicant){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM applicants WHERE id_mis = '".$idapplicant."' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $row['fname'];
} 
require('connection.php'); 
include ('function.php');
$fname1 = getinfoid($conn,'2');
?>
I'm <?php echo $fname1 ?>
```

Alternatively, you can return whole row from your function like this:

```
function getinfoid($conn,$idapplicant){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM applicants WHERE id_mis = '".$idapplicant."' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    return mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}
require('connection.php'); 
include ('function.php');
$useDetails = getinfoid($conn,'2');
?>
I'm <?php echo $useDetails['fname'] ?>
```

Comment: Probably remove the loop and return all the selected columns in an array and let the caller fetch any specific field?

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesn't return anything, those assigned variables stay in the scope of the function. If there is always just one row to fetch, you can do it like this:

```
function getinfoid($conn,$idapplicant){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM applicants WHERE id_mis = '".$idapplicant."' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    return mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

Then you can call this function and echo your variable:

```
$row = getinfoid($conn,'2');
?>
I'm <?php echo $row['fname'] ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare variable $fname1 as global and access the variable. Assuming only single record is returned.

function.php

```
<?php
        $fname1 = "";
        function getinfoid($conn,$idapplicant){
        global $fname1;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM applicants WHERE id_mis = '".$idapplicant."' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $prefix=$row['prefix'];
        $fname1=$row['fname'];
        $mname1=$row['mname'];
        $lname1=$row['lname'];
        $gender=$row['gender'];
        $addr=$row['addr'];
        }
    }
?>
```

view.php

```
<?php 
require('connection.php'); 
include ('function.php');
getinfoid($conn,'2');
?>
I'm <?php echo $fname1 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        function getinfoid($conn,$idapplicant){

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM applicants WHERE id_mis = '".$idapplicant."' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
        return $row
    }
?>

 <?php 
    require('connection.php'); 
    include ('function.php');
    $data = getinfoid($conn,'2');
    ?>
I'm <?php echo $data['firstname'] ?>
```